# Privacy data concern: Facebook account appearing with a search for phone number, despite it never being added - what should I do?

Tags: privacy, facebook, account-security, deletion

Something that's concerned me recently is "doxing" or the searching for and posting of personal information. Recently I carried out essentially an audit of my personal security online and discovered a search engine that is for exactly this purpose.

Curious, I put in my phone number and was shocked to find that this returned my Facebook profile.

I have never added my phone number to my Facebook profile, but I did have the Facebook app installed on my device previously.

How can I remove such details from my profile or at least ensure that this information is hidden better?

Comment: This is indeed a Facebook support question, not an InfoSec question.  Facebook is the correct place to figure out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I believe this is a good question for InfoSec for informational purposes, to see an example of privacy protection gone awry / ignored, and why we should care about it.  Yes, getting it fixed would probably be best done through Facebook support.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think FB is interested in fixing this. The best you can hope for is that they will remove this piece of data from public view. It'll remain on their servers, though, and now as confirmed data. And it will eventually turn up elsewhere.

Comment: `and discovered a search engine that is for exactly this purpose` would you mind sharing which one it is, I'm curious to see how I do.

Comment: @TomHart this particular site is called pipl.com.

Comment: @Xander - you're very likely right about that, but have you ever tried asking anything at Facebook support? They're among the least, well, supportive.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been put on hold.  Protecting privacy data, and the results of what happens when it is not protected is part of Information Security.  I routinely get scam calls, and the scammer knows my name and number, and that I have a Windows computer, so they are getting that information somewhere (perhaps from something stupid like this, or perhaps just the phone book, but I should be unlisted).  The content of the question I felt was a good fit here.  I edited the question title to hopefully fit better.

Comment: I agree with @Jonathan . Facebook has no incentive to solve this. So the question is what an individual can do. That is not limited to "contact FB support". Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't much you can do about it besides deleting your Facebook profile (different from deactivating it - though I'm sure in both cases nothing is *really* deleted).

As for how Facebook got your number - they have a feature in their mobile apps which allows people to upload their contacts to Facebook - if many of your friends had this enabled (and the app is really pushy about enabling it), eventually Facebook will realize "that many people have this number for this person's name - it must be their number".

Comment: This is one more reason not to install the FB app. Of course, some phones have it pre-installed. In which case you should remove or at least disable it. Also, remember that FB owns WhatsApp.

Comment: @S.L.Barth you should be able to at least deny access to your contacts - though I agree it's a bit of a problem for WhatsApp.

Comment: I'd be curious to know whether, as a European Citizen, this somehow breaches my right to privacy, given I likely never gave them permission to?

Comment: Even if you delete your profile successfully, Facebook will still have and build your "shadow profile".  https://www.dailydot.com/news/facebook-shadow-profiles-privacy-faq/ .

Comment: @nobetterdan Not sure. Knowing FB, they have some small print in their T&C when you signed up. It might be a good question for [Law.SE] Stack Exchange, but keep in mind that they do **not** offer legal advice. And, of course, to be received well, the question should show prior research.

Comment: @S.L.Barth you're probably right about their T&C's. If there's one thing that FB are good at, it's protecting their own arses. There's very likely nothing I can do - thankfully little or no updated information is available publicly on my profile, but was just taken aback when I saw it pop up. And the upside is that no other information pops up for my phone number.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: It doesn't matter to what terms of service Facebook made you agree. In the EU you can unilaterally revoke your permission to use personal data as long as it's not required to provide the service or if you don't want to receive the service any longer. Whether FB respects that is another matter. They've been fighting tooth and nail against this stuff in Ireland for years, dragging out the cases and making it as difficult as possible for everybody involved, which is close to saying "we know we're wrong; we just hope you give up before we have to concede to it."

Comment: @nobetterdan it's an interesting question that's probably relevant to *all* apps that store contacts in some way - any service that stores my phonebook or my email contact list will contain personal information of people who haven't given permission for them to store their info and would prefer not to do it; heck, most of them haven't given *me* any explicit, official permission to store their name&phone number, I may have gotten their number from a friend and not themselves.

Comment: If people then start uploading pictures into their profile which you are in and they decide to tag you (even if you don't have a facebook profile) then facebook can have a virtual profile of you.